# jqPlot line graph with gaps

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I have been able to create horizontal line graphing with caps by creating a new series for every timespan in my dataset. 
While this reflects the look I am going for, I am wondering if this is the most efficient way to achieve my goal.

```
public class PlayerSession 
{
    public string PlayerSessionId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutDateTime { get; set; }
}

@model List<PlayerSession>
@{  
    List<List<List<string>>> series = new List<List<List<string>>>();
    foreach(PlayerSession playerSession in this.Model)
    {
        series.Add(new List<List<string>> { 
            new List<string> {
                playerSession.LoginDateTime.ToString(),
                playerSession.PlayerName                
            },
            new List<string> {
                playerSession.LogoutDateTime.ToString(),
                playerSession.PlayerName                
            }
        });     
    }   
}
<div id="player-session-graph"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.jqplot('player-session-graph', @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(series)),{
            seriesDefaults: {
                showMarker: false,
                color: '#446C32',
                lineWidth: 10,
                lineCap: 'butt'
            },
            axes: {
                yaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer },
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "%a, %b %e, %Y", angle: -30
                    },
                    min: '2013-05-19',
                    max: '2013-05-25',
                    tickInterval: '1 day'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Any insight on a more efficient way to plot these lines would be welcomed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [jqPlot documentation about bar charts](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-barRenderer-js.html), you can specify :

```
barWidth  : z
```

In the rendererOptions{} part. Where z represents the width of the bar in pixels. You can also specify barPadding and barMargin if you have several bars at the same axis value.

Comment: I believe that bar width refers to width if the bar, assuming a vertical orientation.

Comment: It will produce a lighter bar (or a thicker one)